# Could not map the json data to pojo class using retrofit

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2

As I viewed the success API response, it seems it is sending the data but the data could not load to its corresponding Pojo class, where the size of ArrayList seems null. The POJO class structure seems fine from my side but could not figure out what the problem is. Here I've provided my log screenshot which returned the API data and the Log I kept to view the ArrayList size:

[image: My Log screenshot]

**API Response:**

```
{
  "achievementList": [
    {
        "id": "somerandomuuid2",
        "name": "Foodie",
        "url": "https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/achievement-icon-icon-11553495882s4jdqrtwe2.png",
        "rewardPoint": 50,
        "description": "Order 500 Food items.",
        "earnPoint": 500,
        "userPoint": 450,
        "achieved": false
    },
    {
        "id": "somerandomuuid3",
        "name": "Explorer",
        "url": "https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/achievement-icon-icon-11553495882s4jdqrtwe2.png",
        "rewardPoint": 50,
        "description": "Book more than 100 tickets.",
        "earnPoint": 100,
        "userPoint": 0,
        "achieved": false
    }
],
   "totalRewardPoints": 0
}
```

**Achievements (POJO Class)**

```
data class Achievements(
@Json(name = "achievementList")
var achievementsList: ArrayList<AchievementsList>
)

data class AchievementsList(
@Json(name = "id")
var id: String?,

@Json(name = "name")
var name: String?,

@Json(name = "url")
var url: String?,

@Json(name = "rewardPoint")
var rewardPoint: Int?,

@Json(name = "description")
var description: String?,

@Json(name = "earnPoint")
var earnPoint: Int?,

@Json(name = "userPoint")
var userPoint: Int?,

@Json(name = "achieved")
var achieved: Boolean?
)
```

**APIService**

```
fun getUserAchievements(
context: AppCompatActivity,
userId: String,
listener: OnAchievementsListener
) {
APIClient.normalRequest.getUserAchievements(userId)
    .enqueue(object : Callback<Achievements> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Achievements>, t: Throwable) {
            listener.onFailure(ResponseCodes.badRequest, t.localizedMessage!!)
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<Achievements>,
            response: Response<Achievements>
        ) {
            when (response.code()) {
                ResponseCodes.success -> {
                    Log.i("ProfileActivity: ", "Response: ${response.body()}")
                    response.body()?.let { listener.onSuccess(it) }
                }
                else -> {
                    when (response.code()) {
                    listener.onFailure(response.code(), "Something went wrong")

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Activity**

```
private fun getAchievementsList() {
    appPreferences?.getString(AppPreferences.UUID)?.let {
        getUserAchievements(this, it, object : OnAchievementsListener {
            override fun onFailure(code: Int, description: String) {
                Utils.showToast(this@ProfileActivity, "$code, $description")
            }

            override fun onSuccess(achievements: Achievements?) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Size: ${achievements?.achievementsList?.size}")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`@SerializedName("achievementList")`

instead of

`@Json(name = "achievementList")`

in POJO class all field

Comment: How does that solve the problem? OP is probably using moshi and not gson for json parsing

Comment: I've used the same annotation (@Json) in all of my previous Pojo classes it seems working for them but don't know what's wrong with this one.

Comment: Omg!! It works, thank you so much dude @Dinesh. I don't know how '@Json' annotation does not work with this one. You saved my day, I spent lots of my time on debugging. Anyway, it works, thanks again.